# How to configure a dedicated circuit for an back-up electrical supply

Tags: electrical, generator, circuit

My family home is heated by a gas furnace and blower that are supplied with a low voltage slot on the electrical panel. On considering what to do in the case of an extended power outage, we considered setting up a manual transfer switch. However, the cost is by far more expensive than we could afford at this time. Is it possible in any other method to supply power to the circuit directly from a gas powered generator?

Comment: What kind of transfer switch were you considering? There are dedicated products for this such as the Reliance TF151. Even with an electrician to install I would expect that to be $500 at most. The older cheaper hack of adding a plug to the furnace is specifically not allowed by NEC 400.7.

Comment: To make sub-$100 recommendations, we will need to see a photo of your panel (door open, not necessary to unscrew the deadfront cover) including its factory provided labeling if readily available. [edit] your question to add photos - it helps to either have registered your acc-- oh what am I saying? You're a regular.

Answer (score 5):

Well first, they sell a thing called a "transfer switch" which has 6, 8 or 10 switchable circuits on it.  These things are obscenely overpriced, obsolete and badly designed - UL would never approve their design today.   They are the darling of generator salesmen who get a big kickback on them via sales commissions.   Their selling point is they can work on any panel (any pre-2005 panel, that is.)

Consider a **generator interlock** - $30 to $80.  This is a "sliding plate" affair with a bit of engineering in it, that simply prevents your main breaker from being turned on at the same time as a generator back-feed breaker.  You install a regular breaker in the correct place and use it as an "alternate main breaker" **to feed the whole panel**.

Now you do need a lick of common sense for this to work - you can't power *everything* - so you shut off all breakers except what you need, and turn off loads on those circuits except what you need.  Having the refrigerator run (120 watts/1 amp) - perfectly fine. Having a microwave also run - maybe not.

The generator breaker is then wired outside to an **inlet**, and we can show you how to make a cheap inlet. It's no more complicated than installing a branch circuit.

The trick to generator interlocks is they must be fit to your panel.  There's some "craft" to that, and that's why generator salesmen hate them.  Easier to talk you into $10 a month more lol.